Postfix / Courier / Amavis - Move spam to junk folder
Running Postfix / Courier / Amavis / Spamassassin on my Debian 12 server. Using this setup for quite some time now. Everything is configured and works well (DMARC, DKIM SPF, MTA-STS etc.). Incoming spam mails gets marked as ***SPAM***, which is great. But I would like to have a way to directly move them to the junk folder instead of just marking them as spam in the inbox. Haven't really found anything, I've already also thought of writing a script doing that by triggering it when a new mail arrives. But I'm sure there's a much better / built-in way to do that, that's why I'm asking the mailserver pro's here.
